# How can I make this slider have the first two big picture and then be on two columns?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this site:

EN:[link](http://www.moment-of-style.com/?___store=en&___from_store=ru)

RU:[link](http://www.moment-of-style.com/?___store=ru&___from_store=en)

On each page there is a slide

**Slider on Russian** is ok, you do not have to make any changes.The slider in Russian, the first 3 pictures are great, and then two columns.

**Slider in English** is not ok. I want to be large first two pictures and then be on two columns.

**CODE HTML FOR SLIDER IN RU:**

```
<div id="slider" class="home-blocks ru-slide">
    <div id="left-slide">
        <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/mos-banner-promotion-27-05-15-2.jpg"}}" />
        <a href="special-projects">
            <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/ballet5.png"}}" />
        </a>
        <a href="special-projects">
            <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/ballet6.png"}}" />
        </a>
        <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/444_1.jpg"}}" />
    </div>

    <div id="right-slide">
        <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/17.jpg"}}" />
        <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/17.jpg"}}" />
        <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/22.jpg"}}" />
        <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/1.jpg"}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**CODE HTML FOR SLIDER IN EU:**

```
<div id="slider" class="home-blocks en-slide">
    <div id="left-slide">
        <a href="special-projects">
             <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/ballet5.png"}}" />
        </a>
        <a href="special-projects">
            <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/ballet6.png"}}" />
        </a>
      <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/444_1.jpg"}}" />
    </div>
    <div id="right-slide">
        <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/17.jpg"}}" />
        <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/17.jpg"}}" />
        <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/22.jpg"}}" />
        <img alt="" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/1.jpg"}}" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script JQuery slider in the RU**

```
if (jQuery('#slider').hasClass('ru-slide')) {
    if (index == -1 || index == 0 || index == 1) {
        jQuery('#left-slide').addClass('full-banner');
    } else {
        jQuery('#left-slide').removeClass('full-banner');
    }
} else {}
```

**Script JQuery slider in the EN**

```
if (jQuery('#slider').hasClass('en-slide')){
    if (index == 0 || index == 1){
        jQuery('#left-slide').addClass('full-banner');
    } else {
        jQuery('#left-slide').removeClass('full-banner');
    }
}
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
#left-slide{
    width:47.5%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#right-slide{
    float:right;
    width:47.5%;
}

.full-banner{
    width:100% !important;
}
```

So again ... I want the first two pictures of the slider EN to be large and the rest of the picture is the two columns as in Russian ...

I hope I managed to make you understand what they want.
Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like wrapping your single and double images in a div and sliding those would be much simpler.

Comment: I do not understand what you say ... can you show me an example please?